# velocity.js duration different when animated two properties

Tags: javascript, animation, velocity.js

I'm trying to animate scale and rotation of an element (which works), but the scale animation is done way before the rotation finishes. The div keeps rotating while the scale animation is done after about 300ms.
I haven't found a syntax in which one can specify the duration for separate properties (I thought the duration should be for all specified properties).
Here's the code, any tips appreciated:

```
$('#el').velocity({
   rotateZ:[ 1440, 'easeInOut', 0 ],
   scale:[ 1, 'spring', 0 ]
},{
    duration:1000
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, the animation doesn't end at 300ms, it's just the spring easing makes it look like. The spring easing function doesn't move much in the second hald od the animation. Try spring easing with some other parameters, like:

```
$('#el').velocity({
  rotateZ:[ 360, 'easeInOut', 0.001 ],
  scale:[ 1, [20,0.2], 0.001 ]
},{
  duration:1000
});
```

Also note that velocity seems to handle 0 values as undefined parameters, so I use `0.001` instead. (it only makes difference on subsequent animations)

Comment: Ah yes, seems like spring easing doesn't care about the duration much. I just changed the scale's easing to easeInOut as well. Thanks!